# udev не запускает правило на ACTION=="add"

Tags: linux, udev

Необходимо написать правило для демона udev, которое запускало бы скрипт на событие **подключения** флешки.

Написал простое правило (имя файла 10-alabel.rules, самый высокий приоритет):

```
KERNEL=="sd*", ENV{ID_FS_UUID}=="a004d31c-120d-4593-b051-6ef8951d52d0" RUN+="/lib/udev/create_virtual.sh %k"
```

Содержимое **create_virtual.sh**:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo $1 >> /home/accumplus/1.txt

exit 0
```

Это правило срабатывает на извлечение флешки. Мне же надо на добавление. Дописываю параметр action:

```
ACTION=="add", KERNEL=="sd*", ENV{ID_FS_UUID}=="a004d31c-120d-4593-b051-6ef8951d52d0" RUN+="/lib/udev/create_virtual.sh %k"
```

После этого правило отказывается работать в принципе. Думал, что это из-за наличия параметра %k (устройство скорее всего ещё не было добавлено в каталог dev, а я уже ссылаюсь на его имя), но удаление этого параметра ничего не изменило.

Как решить эту проблему?

**UPD**

Без указания переменной окружения UUID правило срабатывает. Попробовал вывести значение этой переменной окружения в скрипте, который запускается при добавлении флешки:

```
echo $ID_FS_UUID >> /home/accumplus/1.txt
```

Выводит именно то значение, которое я указываю в условии правила:

```
a004d31c-120d-4593-b051-6ef8951d52d0
```

Comment: начните с малого: оставьте только `SUBSYSTEM=="block"` и вызов скрипта. а в скрипте сохраняйте переменные окружения в файл и смотрите, что ещё добавить, чтобы ваш скрипт срабатывал только  один раз при подключении нужного вам блочного устройства.

Comment: Оставил ACTION, RUN и добавил SUBSYSTEM - правило срабатывает на извлечение флешки... Какие именно переменные окружения нужно отслеживать?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin а, нет. Просто скрипт выполняется с небольшим запозданием. Такая строка работает.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin указал результаты в вопросе

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в приоритете. По всей видимости устройство не успевает получить UUID, поэтому и условия моего правила не срабатывали. Переименовав файл правил, указав большее число, я добился желаемого результата.